# My sphere falls through the floor which is made in blender

Tags: unity, collider

I am developing a game with a club, and yesterday I requested a floor with a hole and the people from the art team made one for me and gave it to me in a `.fbx` format (it was originally made in blender), and I imported it in unity and placed my gameobject like normal. Then when I hit play, the gameobject fell through the floor. (I used a `box collider` for the floor and a `sphere collider` for my gameobject since it is a sphere)

 I asked my advisor and he asked me to add `mesh collider` and assign the mesh (I have enabled `convex` and the ball is on top of it, not burying in the floor at all), and after I assigned the mesh, which is the surface that the ball is rolling on, but the ball still falls through the floor.

 The current status: I have enabled `Rigidbody` for the ball and the mass is set to 1, and the collider for the ball is a `sphere collider`. The collider for the floor is a `mesh collider` and the `mesh` is the surface on which the ball is rolling upon, the `convex` is enabled as well.

Comment: Are the ball's and the floor's [physics layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) interacting with each other? Or, is the ball moving too fast?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the information given here. Placing a sphere on top of a mesh with a mesh collider or box collider (box collider being a better option than the convex mesh collider, if the shape fits) with some thickness, on interacting physics layers, and with no colliders marked as triggers, causes the ball to rest on the mesh. Try walking us through the steps to produce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, starting from a new empty project. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test potential solutions.

Comment: DMGregory is right. I, for instance, need pictures to fully understand a problem, can you add some?

Comment: I've found the problem (actually my advisor helped me find it): the box collider is very small and inside the ground object, which has no effect on the ground (I don't even know where does that collider come from...). Thank you for the help anyway!